# Добавление объекта в список в контроллере

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Есть `@GetMapping` и `@PostMapping` методы.
Вопрос в том, как, передавая значения из `@PostMapping` в `@GetMapping`, обновлять список, который отображается в `@GetMapping`.
Или остается только вариант с внешним списком и очисткой его по кнопке?

Get controller:

```
@GetMapping("/mobile/setloadingcode/{truckID}/{cargoID}")
public String getSetLoadingCode(@PathVariable(value = "truckID") Long truckID,
                                @PathVariable(value = "cargoID") Long cargoID, Model model) {

    InboundTruck inboundTruck = inboundTruckRepository.getById(truckID);
    model.addAttribute("id", inboundTruck.getId());
    return "/mobile/setloadingcode";
}
```

Post controller:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/mobile/setloadingcode/{truckID}/{cargoID}")
    public String postSetLoadingCode(@PathVariable(value = "truckID") Long truckID,
                                     @PathVariable(value = "cargoID") Long cargoID, String loadingSearchCode, Model model) {
        Cargo cargo = cargoService.findById(cargoID);
        cargo.setLoadingSearchCode(loadingSearchCode);
        cargoService.editCargo(cargo);
        return getSetLoadingCode(truckID, cargoID, model);
    }
```

Мне необходимо при вводе данных, добавлять их в список и через thymeleaf выводить их на экране. проблема в том, что если я передаю через `@PostMapping` лист в `@GetMapping` то получается, что лист пересоздается каждый раз, когда страница обновляется. Каким образом можно передавать данные без обновления листа?

Comment: Как и откуда получается список если пользователь сразу выполняет GET запрос (не при редиректе с POST запроса)? Как происходит передача данных при редиректе?

Comment: @Alexandr метод POST запроса возвращает GET, т.е. return getMethod(model, List<String> string); для примера

Comment: Если есть возможность, то приложите код Вашего контроллера  в сам вопрос

Comment: @Alexandr добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Напрямую методы контроллеров не вызываются. Вам необходимо сделать `redirect` или `forward`. Например, `return "redirect:/mobile/setloadingcode/" + truckID + "/" + cargoID`. На сколько  понимаю при вызове `cargoService` происходят сохранение в БД и при отображении эти данные можно отобразить из БД. Также не понятно про какой список была речь, т.к. в коде ничего подобного не видно.

Comment: Описал проблему в вопрос